# Find the length of a segment in a triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In the drawing, if $BF=3$ and $DE=4$ and $\angle BCD = 90º$, find the lenght of $CF$

**My try:**
I drew the segment $BE=CE$, because $AE$ is the angle bisector.
After that i chased angles, and i found a lot of similar triangles, but after applying all the relations, i can't find the length of $CF$. I tried with sine and cosine law repeteadly, but it didn't work for me neither.

Any hints?
[image]

Comment: I guess you have not mentioned that $\angle BCD$ is a right angle.

Comment: @Lwins edited, thanks

Comment: And a quick observation: $BE \neq CE$ in general.

Answer (score 1):

$\measuredangle FCE=\measuredangle CED=x.$, 
From, $\measuredangle ACB = 90 -2x$ and $\measuredangle ACE = 90-x$ and since, $$\measuredangle ACB + \measuredangle FCE = \measuredangle ACE$$. So
$$90- 2x + \measuredangle FCE = 90 -x$$ => $\measuredangle FCE = x$, $\measuredangle CED =x$, as it is alternate angle to $\measuredangle FCE$.
$$\cos x = \frac{DE}{CE} = \frac{4}{CE} => CE = \frac{4}{\cos x}$$.
Let $y = BC - DE - BF => BC = 7 + y$. 
So, from $\triangle ACE$, 
$\sin x = \frac{CE}{AC}$. 
From $\triangle ABC$, $\sin 2x = \frac{BC}{AC}$.
Dividing, $$\frac{\sin 2x}{\sin x} = 2\cos x = \frac{BC}{CE} = \frac{7 + y}{CE}$$
Substituting for CE,
$$2\cos x = \frac{7 + y}{CE} = \frac{7 + y}{\frac{4}{\cos x}} => 8 = 7 + y => y = 1 => CF = DE + y = 5$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $ACEB$ is cyclic and $CB||DE$, we obtain:
$$\measuredangle FCE=\measuredangle CED=x.$$
Thus, $$4=CE\cos{x}=CF\cos^2x=(BC-3)\cos^2x=(3\cot{x}\tan2x-3)\cos^2x.$$
Can you end it now?

I got $CF=5.$

Comment: Did you mean $\measuredangle FCE=\measuredangle CED=x$?

Comment: @Seyed It was typo. I fixed. Thank you!